# Remove unused packages from conda environment

Tags: python, conda

I was provided with a complex Python program and a conda environment file for the dependencies of this program. However, I realized after installing the environment from the environment file that most packages in this environment are not used by this Python program. Is there a way to automatically identify the packages that are not used and remove them from the environment to make it smaller ? I guess that conda doesn't provide this functionality as it would require to parse the Python code to identify the packages that are imported or not, and conda is language agnostic.

I know the existence of `conda clean --packages`, but this command only clear the local cache of conda, which is not what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using "conda remove"? This might be helpful https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html

Comment: The thing is that the only way I could know what to remove would be for me to manually go over each file of the Python program, and there is a lot of them. I want an automated way of doing this

Comment: I don't know any way to automate it, but why don't you remove all the packages installed in conda and then install packages which are required. This is far easier to find and remove packages manually (one by one)!

Comment: The `conda env update --prune -f minimal_env.yaml` would have been useful for this, but [the `--prune` functionality has been broken since Conda v4.4](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7279), unfortunately. You would still to have had to collect the required package list yourself though.